# 182 reputation on Arqade, but cannot chat in affiliated room

Tags: support, reputation, chat

I am an active user on the Stack Exchange network, and participate in a few of the sites. I just heard about the chat room [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge), and it seems I can’t chat there. However, I have:

- 182 reputation on Arqade
- 99 reputation on Stack Overflow
- 81 reputation on Codegolf

I am very confused why it says I need 20 or more reputation to chat. I look on my Stack Exchange page, and it shows no reputation. Why?

Here is what the chatroom looks like for me:
[image]

Comment: Are you logged in to chat?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in, when I click on the Stack Exchange Network button, it brings me to stackexchange.com with me logged in. There is no other login button on the chat page that I can find.

Comment: So, at the top bar on chat, you see your user name, and not a "log in" link?

Comment: There is no top bar. Adding picture.

Comment: And when you go to: http://chat.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: It has a bar there. I can't seem to access The Bridge from there though.

Comment: I know. But does it show your name or "log in"? You can access the bridge if you click "Rooms" then "All" - you can search for it in the list.

Comment: It shows my name, meaning (to my knowledge) that I'm logged in.

Comment: That is what I was trying to determine. Click your name there - you will see your user profile on chat. What do you have near the "parent user"? You can change it to be arqade, at which point all should be well.

Answer (score 9):

I seem to have figured it out. The parent account associated with my account was Stack Overflow (even though I had enough reputation on there...), and it showed 14 reputation. However, switching my parent account over to gaming.stackexchange.com seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Also, another thing to note, be warned that ABS (Adblock Super) may get rid of some of the bars. Just realized this :P