# Can we chat in rooms if we get 20 rep in any site?

Tags: support, chat

I just joined a chat room and it requires me to get 20 rep on the site the chat room it is based on. So just to chat in that room, I have to get 20 rep just to chat. Not counting the time for the server to reset.

Please think about adding this feature in Stack Exchange as it won't be so annoying to try to get 20 rep at a subject you may not be so familiar with.

Comment: Very highly related; suggested reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257816/demystifying-chat-reputation-requirements

Comment: You don't know how annoying it is to have many sites for different chats. Some use the same, some don't. Last I checked there was 2 chat sites for meta

Comment: By the way, seems that now you can chat in the Tavern, as you have 20 reps :)

Comment: I know :D I am just waiting for the server to restart

Comment: @ExplosionsPlus Not restart, refresh

Comment: Is this question to get your 20 rep to chat? :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Once you get 20 rep, say, on Arqade, you gain a ability to chat in any room on chat.stackexchange, these means in the room of any site excluding Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow rooms which are located on the chat.Meta.StackExchange and chat.StackOverflow respectively. This means that chatting in the chat.MSE and chat.SO rooms requires earning 20 rep on MSE and SO, or looking at the second point.
2. Once you get 200 rep on one site, the assoc bonus is added to any site you've joined and will join. This means you'll have ability to chat in *any* rooms you want, excluding, of course private and gallery ones.
3. If it's very necessary for you to chat in some room for *the reasons*, a moderator can always grant you the write access to any room.

Comment: @Exp its located on chat.Meta.StackExchange - look at the address bar. Then read my post again :)

Comment: @exp Oh, please read the second point then.

Comment: @Explosions bottom line is, as Nicael points out, the rep calculation towards gaining the privilege to chat in meta.SE's chatrooms is separate. On another note, it seems that a net rep of 20 in all of the SE network (excluding meta and SO again) allows you to chat in all of the chat.SE rooms.

Answer (score 6):

There are three chat systems:

1. Stack Overflow chat.
2. Meta Stack Exchange chat.
3. Stack Exchange chat (for all other SE sites).

Each system is independent. For SO chat, you need 20 rep on SO; for MSE chat, you need 20 rep on MSE; for SE chat, you need 20 rep aggrigate across all other SE sites. Yes, this system is frankly weird, but it’s an artefact of history. Tidying it up would probably be more trouble than it’s worth.